# Accessing NPM on Windows behind a proxy WITHOUT storing the password

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, visual-studio-2017, kerberos

I am using NPM from Visual Studio 2017 and from command line.

From my investigation NPM doesn't authenticate using Windows authentication to access http://registry.npmjs.org/ , so npm is blocked by the corporate proxy.

To sort out the problem, the solution below works but with a SECURITY HOLE:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy http://user:pass@ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://user:pass@ip:port
npm config set proxy http://user:pass@ip:port
npm set strict-ssl false
```

This will store the password in BASE64 encoded text in NPM config (not good!)

An alternative solution is to always provide the proxy settings with every command to avoid storing the password, but this is still not ideal, such as:

```
npm --without-ssl --insecure --proxy http://user:pass@ip:port install package-name
```

I have tried CNTLM which is more secure in storing the password, but you will have to update CNTLM everytime you update your password, so it is not ideal.

**Can we setup NPM to authenticate to carry on the credentials from VS or command line like using Kerberos or any other secure method?**

Comment: Hi Adam, were you able to find a solution to this problem?